# Will there be any changes to Web Parts in SharePoint 15?

Tags: web-part, 2013

I’ve search the web, as I usually do, but I does not find any useful information. Maybe it’s way too early to know of any specifics yet, but if anyone has any info on the question – please let me know.

*Will there be any changes to Web Parts in SharePoint 15?*

Comment: I don't think so because the world ends in 2012

Comment: There's no such thing as "SharePoint 2015" now - it's SharePoint 15 (because it belongs to the Office 15 products line) and officially will be named SharePoint 2012 or 2013.

Comment: Making this a Community Wiki as it is more of a general discussion question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only a few informations about the next version of SP, called SP 15. But I can imagine that there will be more informations in the next weeks. But I dont think that they havnt changed any well-known features. Maybe there will be some changes but the most common behaviour will stay the same.

Something I have heard is that they have:
- Changes to the Object Model
- Switched to pure HTML5
- Switche to .NET 4.0

But this infrormations are from other threads, so I am not sure about this changes.

Best Regards

Jan

Comment: The .NET 4 I knew of but not HTML 5. Thanx for your answer!